# How to test an email function in Springboot using MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I have this sendmail function that I want to Test in Junit 4 using MockMvc.
I have provided my test case and **WiserAssertions.java** file I am using to test the function.

When testing the Junit test case I am getting the AssertionError that

> java.lang.AssertionError: No message from [demoprojintern@gmail.com] found!
>       at com.appointment.request.controller.WiserAssertions.lambda$7(WiserAssertions.java:67)

**Can someone help me out what am I missing?**

**sendmail()** function

```
 public void sendmail(Request request) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        String email = request.getEmail();
        int requestId1 = request.getRequestId();
        String requestId = Integer.toString(requestId1);
        String name = request.getLegalName();
        String cause = request.getCause();
        String doa = request.getDateOfAppointment();
        String toa = request.getAppointmentTime();
        int status = request.getRequestStatus();

        String generic = "Hello, " + name + "<br><br>" + "Your request with Request ID: " + requestId + " for " + "the cause of "
                + cause + " on " + doa + " at " + toa + " has been ";
        String regards = "<br><br><br>Thanks and Regards,<br>";

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<my-email-id>", "<my-email-id's password");
            }
        });
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("<my-email-id>", false));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
        msg.setSubject("Regarding your Appointment Request");
        msg.setContent(" ", "text/html");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        if (status == 0) {
            String messageForPendingRequest = generic + "<strong>RECEIVED</strong>." + regards;
            messageBodyPart.setContent(messageForPendingRequest, "text/html");
        }
        if (status == 1) {
            String messageForPendingRequest = generic + "<strong>APPROVED</strong>." + regards;
            messageBodyPart.setContent(messageForPendingRequest, "text/html");
        }
        if (status == 2) {
            String messageForPendingRequest = generic + "<strong>SUGGESTED</strong>." + regards;
            messageBodyPart.setContent(messageForPendingRequest, "text/html");
        }

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
```

These are the dependencies of my pom.xml for sending the email and testing the mail respectively

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>subethasmtp</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is my junit test case

```
 private Wiser wiser;

    @Test
    public void send() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request(1234, "Richie Rich", "<patient's-email-id>", "Brain", 27, "2019-12-17", "13:00", 0, "", "", "");
        String email = request.getEmail();
        int requestId1 = request.getRequestId();
        String requestId = Integer.toString(requestId1);
        String name = request.getLegalName();
        String cause = request.getCause();
        String doa = request.getDateOfAppointment();
        String toa = request.getAppointmentTime();
        String generic = "Hello, " + name + "<br><br>" + "Your request with Request ID: "
                + requestId + " for " + "the cause of "
                + cause + " on " + doa + " at " + toa + " has been ";
        String regards = "<br><br><br>Thanks and Regards,<br>";
        String jsonRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/sendemail").content(jsonRequest).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        // assert
        WiserAssertions.assertReceivedMessage(wiser)
                .from("<sender-mail-id>")
                .to(email)
                .withSubject("Regarding your Appointment Request")
                .withContent(generic + "<strong>RECEIVED</strong>." + regards);
    }
```

This is my **WiserAssertions.java** that I got from a blog

```
public class WiserAssertions {
        private final List<WiserMessage> messages;

        private WiserAssertions(List<WiserMessage> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        public static WiserAssertions assertReceivedMessage(Wiser wiser) {
            return new WiserAssertions(wiser.getMessages());
        }

        private static Supplier<AssertionError> assertionError(String errorMessage, String... args) {
            return () -> new AssertionError(MessageFormat.format(errorMessage, args));
        }

        public static <T> T unchecked(ThrowingSupplier<T> supplier) {
            try {
                return supplier.get();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public WiserAssertions from(String from) {
            findFirstOrElseThrow(m -> m.getEnvelopeSender().equals(from),
                    assertionError("No message from [{0}] found!", from));
            return this;
        }

        public WiserAssertions to(String to) {
            findFirstOrElseThrow(m -> m.getEnvelopeReceiver().equals(to),
                    assertionError("No message to [{0}] found!", to));
            return this;
        }

        public WiserAssertions withSubject(String subject) {
            Predicate<WiserMessage> predicate = m -> subject.equals(unchecked(getMimeMessage(m)::getSubject));
            findFirstOrElseThrow(predicate,
                    assertionError("No message with subject [{0}] found!", subject));
            return this;
        }

        public WiserAssertions withContent(String content) {
            findFirstOrElseThrow(m -> {
                ThrowingSupplier<String> contentAsString =
                        () -> ((String) getMimeMessage(m).getContent()).trim();
                return content.equals(unchecked(contentAsString));
            }, assertionError("No message with content [{0}] found!", content));
            return this;
        }

        private void findFirstOrElseThrow(Predicate<WiserMessage> predicate, Supplier<AssertionError> exceptionSupplier) {
            messages.stream().filter(predicate)
                    .findFirst().orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier);
        }

        private MimeMessage getMimeMessage(WiserMessage wiserMessage) {
            return unchecked(wiserMessage::getMimeMessage);
        }

        interface ThrowingSupplier<T> {
            T get() throws Throwable;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you not using Spring Mail?

Comment: I suggest you debug it. It must be just some simple text assertion error.